# How to save array in .txt (C)

Tags: c

I would like to be able to read the file and then assign the .txt values ​​in the array for the next time I start the program.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of the function fwrite() on the site cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) contains an example of writing an array to file and then reading it back. This seems to be exactly what you want.